# Delete & Recreate the service with some extra parameters

Tags: pi-3

I see that my raspbian is running the transmission-daemon.service is running with the log parameter-

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status transmission-daemon.service
● transmission-daemon.service - Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-01-25 12:18:13 IST; 30min ago
 Main PID: 739 (transmission-da)
   Status: "Idle."
   CGroup: /system.slice/transmission-daemon.service
           └─739 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error
```

However inorder to run this service with the logging enabled, i need to start this service with the switch `--log-file <path to the log file>`. In that way i need this service to be run as

```
/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error --log-file /var/log/transmission.log.
```

I can disable this existing service using `sudo systemctl disable transmission-daemon.service`, But not sure on how to recreate this service with the new switches.

Please suggest.

Comment: This is not Raspberry pi specific, try googling `transmission-daemon log file`. If you are just interesting to see the logs and do not need a specific logfile, it *should* be in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/daemon.log`.

Comment: @jogco: Yes, as you said, this is not Pi specific. As per Transmission documentation, i would need to start the transmission service as per `/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error --log-file /var/log/transmission.log`. But since the service runs as `/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error`, Im not able to get the log file created.

I just need to know how to create this service with the required parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... Your system is starting transmission with the `/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service` script.

So all you need to do is to edit this to include the log file option:

Change the line:

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error`

to

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error --logfile /var/log/transmission.log`

then do a

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

and restart your daemon with

`sudo service transmission-daemon restart`

Note that the logfile option flag is "logfile" not "log-file"

Comment: Wonderful. Let me try this & update you.